# git checkout error: unable to read askpass response in Windows 10

Tags: git, android-studio, windows-10, android-studio-bumblebee

Error occurred while cloning repository in Android Studio

error: unable to read askpass response from
 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1\tmp\intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Resolved above issue with below steps:

1. Click on the File Menu of Android Studio -> Settings -> Expand Version Control
2. Inside Version Control, select Git & Check Use Credential Helper

[image]

Comment: I checked it but then what? what needs to happen?

Comment: Then you start your checkout again, it will ask to enter your credentials.

Comment: With 'git push' and GitLab works too. For me, this answer could be the solution.

Comment: This solution does not help me. I have put login credential when an alert dialog pops from github but It's still showing `error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\91700\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\tmp\intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
` Do you have any other solution please help

Comment: For me above solution worked after putting my credentials when asked while performing git fetch.

Comment: After the above step, I also had to restart Android Studio in order to work

Comment: What does this checkbox do?

Comment: Thanks for the help, your answer saved a lot of time. Add to answer that Android Studio should be restarted (preferably via "invalidate cache and restart") in order to work

Comment: not working for me, I am using Gitlab. I am not getting dialog popup to enter username and password. :(

Answer (score 17):

I simply resolved it by doing Invalidate Caches and Restart.

In Android Studio, Click on `File > Invalidate Caches... > tick all checkboxes > Click Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: Clear VCS Log Caches and Indexes was enough for me

Comment: this method is also working on PHP Storm and Web Storm.

Answer (score 3):

For others that may be having this issue with any IntelliJ product (WebStorm in my case), **disabling the Gitlab plugin** under plugins solved the issue for me.

Credit to Matthew for figuring this out: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-326514/unable-to-read-askpass-response-intellij-git-askpass-local.sh#27-7969570.0-0

Answer (score 2):

It’s happens when credential in git are forgotten **suddenly**.
(I don’t understand why it happens with me after year of working at project).

**Steps to solve problem.**

Open terminal in project’s folder.

```bash
git config --global credential.helper store
```

```bash
git pull
```

Specify your username and password.

If you use corporate GitLab probably you need to use token **INSTEAD** of password (it depends from corporate rules).

> GitLab site -> Your avatar -> Edit profile -> Access Tokens -> Add new token
>
> Don’t set “Expiration date” (or remember about it and re-generate new token after expiration of old token).

Check:

```bash
git fetch
```

Now you can use IDEA and fetch/clone/etc again.

After this steps I solved problem:

```bash
error: unable to read askpass response from '/home/***/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/tmp/intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.***.com': No such device or address
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply resolved it by doing Invalidate Caches and Restart.

In Android Studio, Click on File > Invalidate Caches... > tick all checkboxes > Click Invalidate and Restart

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1- clean your project
2- make invalid cash and restart your project
3- make sure you select the clean cash

Answer (score 0):

you can update or add new credentials through control panel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After spending 5+ hours trying various recommendations suggested - to include invalidating caches - using credential helper - not using credential helper, what finally worked for me:

I was using git LFS, but did't have any large files to upload for this particular project. So I disabled that. I also disabled the github plugin, but left the git plugin active. Then, I SSH'd into the project, and only used terminal commands - not the Intellij IDE.

Also, if you're trying to authenticate using your github password, that did not work for me. Instead, generate a token on the github website and use the token id as the password.

On to the SSH -

you can use gpt to walk you through how to set up your ssh - but here are some notes i took on the process.

github ssh:

1. generate ssh key : ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@gmail.com"
2. add ssh key to ssh agent (this is your private ssh key):eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"  ssh-add /home/directory.sshkeys/ssh

*2 files will appear. The ssh.pub file is the one you need to copy and paste contents into github under settings->SSH and GPG keys->New SSH Key

3. Authenticate: ssh -T git@github.com
4. update the remote URL to use SSH: git remote set-url origin git@github.com:tcdickson/Green-Collectives.git

after this, I was able to troubleshoot a few merge issues and use regular git commands to push.

Some newbie commands:
git pull origin master

git checkout master

git merge master

git merge origin/master

git push origin master

git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories

Rebase your feature branch on top of the updated master branch: git rebase master

Answer (score -3):

You can check in ****Use credential helper**** which helps you check your credential and if you didn't set up that before it would send you a question to login for create credential.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFG8x.png

Comment: duplicate answer