# Initial Push Failed in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, github, repo

I tried creating a git hub repository using Android Studio but I'm getting this error:

```
14:21   Can't finish GitHub sharing process
           Successfully created project 'anomaly' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
           Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
           java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
           at git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:30)
           at git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:58)
           Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
           at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:866)
           at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
           at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:863)
           at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
           at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
           at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
           at... (show balloon)
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456719/git-checkout-error-unable-to-read-askpass-response-in-windows-10 solved my issue with this error

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing this:

**git config --global user.email "example@example.com"**

**git config --global user.name "your_username"**

Comment: What part of the error message makes you think this is the problem?